# Making a dataframe row from a list buffer into one column

Tags: scala, dataframe

I am trying to make a Dataframe from a listbuffer of objects I have.

I have a list buffer of different `Fruit`'s and want to create a Dataframe row with those events(ignoring the columns from the case class)

```
import spark.implicits._

case class Fruit(
                   indentifier: String,
                   name: String)


var fruits= new scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[Any]()

val fruit1 = Fruit("one", "banana")
val fruit2 = Fruit("two", "apple")
val fruit3 = Fruit("three", "orange")

fruits+= fruit1
fruits += fruit2
fruits+= fruit3

val x = fruits.toSeq.toDF()
```

My goal is to create different Rows and later make a Dataframe from those rows

The number of objects in my `fruits` can change as well as the contents. I am trying to have my row in this case be:

```
[{"indentifier":"one", "name":"banana"}, {"indentifier":"two", "name":"apple"}, {"indentifier":"three", "name":"orange"}]


+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|Fruits                                                                                                   
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|[{"indentifier":"one", "name":"banana"}, {"indentifier":"two", "name":"apple"}, {"indentifier":"three", "name":"orange"}]                                                                                                    |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I tried to do `fruits.toSeq.toDF()` but cannot do that because " toDF is not a member of Seq[Any]"

Comment: You should have a `SparkSession` in scope and import it's implicits as `import sparkSession.implicits._`

Answer (score 0):

Can we declare your list buffer as the case class instead of `Any`? If so, this works just fine for me:

```
var fruits= new scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[Fruit]()

val fruit1 = Fruit("one", "banana")
val fruit2 = Fruit("two", "apple")
val fruit3 = Fruit("three", "orange")

fruits+= fruit1
fruits += fruit2
fruits+= fruit3

val x = Seq(fruits).toDF()
// x: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [value: array<struct<indentifier:string,name:string>>]
```

`x` in that case matches the desired output you specified, please note when you `show` it on the `spark-shell` it might look different. Result of `x.show(false)`:

```
+----------------------------------------------+
|value                                         |
+----------------------------------------------+
|[[one, banana], [two, apple], [three, orange]]|
+----------------------------------------------+
```